# perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I am having some URLs in this format. Some URLs contain `&abc=4` and some not.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&abc=4
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&abc=4
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

here `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is string

I want to match URLs which have `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` only and not `&abc=4`(meaning I want to get these type of URLs, only `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, `xxx`)

I know how to write a regular expression which matches the entire url. For example: `/x.*abc=4/`

But how do I write a regular expression that matches only `xxxxxxxxxx` and **not** `&abc=4`?

Comment: first check for a match with xxxx, then check for the absence of abc=4

Comment: probably you also don't want `?abc=4`

Comment: probably you also also don't want ;abc=4

Answer (score 1):

I would use negative look-ahead assertion (Look ahead what is not allowed  to follow my pattern)

```
^(?!.*&abc=4$).*$
```

This pattern will match any string that does not end with `&abc=4`

you can verify it online here: http://www.rubular.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use [negative lookbehind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns). The form is:

```
(?<![&?]abc=4)
```

(this will also exclude `?abc=4`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your URLs are on each line, you can use:

```
([^&]+?)
```

This basically will match anything up to the the first instance of &.

As @Benoit said, you can do this using a zero width expression to negate the capture of the query string, but you would be after a positive lookahead, and not a negative lookbehind, syntax example below:

```
(?=(&[^=]+?\d+)+)
```

As you can see though, this would complicate the expression a touch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a negative lookahead, so what your asking for is everything up to the point that it would not be followed by the &=444 point.  A positive lookahead allows you to say everything up the point that it is followed by this.